# Sign in with Xbox web API

Tags: xbox-live

I need to make users sign in with their Xbox in my application. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
 base_url = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?'
    qs = unquote(urlencode({
        'client_id': 'My client Id',
        'redirect_uri': 'https://localhost:44331',
        'response_type': 'token',
        'display': 'touch',
        'scope': 'service::user.auth.xboxlive.com::MBI_SSL',
        'locale': 'en',
    }))
```

My problem is i'm not sure where to get my Client Id and how to add that scope. I already registered my add in Azure app registration and got my client Id and added the redirect Url but still not working.

Comment: Did you review the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/using-xbox-live/auth/authentication_nav

Comment: Have you found the solution Nick

Answer (score 2):

The `client_id` is supposed to come from an **Application** in your Azure dashboard.

- Go to [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com/) and click “[App Registrations](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade)”.
- If you're in a Directory, you *might* have to click “View all applications from personal account”
- Select your application, *or* create one by clicking “New registration”
- Go to “Overview” on  the left toolbar, if not already selected
- Get `client_id` from the “Application (client) ID” field.
  You may also be interested in:

  - `client_secret` and `client_secret_id`: got from “Certificates & secrets”
  - Configuring allowable `return_url`s: “Authentication”, “Platform Configurations”, “Web”
  - `tenant_id`: Underneath “Azure Active Directory” (found in the *far*-left toolbar accessed by the “Hamburger Menu” in the top-left corner), click “Overview”, then find it under “Tenant information”

---

For a small demo showcasing the *bare minimum* `/oauth20_authorize.srf` can need for Xbox Live authorization, see the `printf`'d URL and the first `curl` call in [`gamertag_to_uuid.sh`](https://gist.github.com/JamesTheAwesomeDude/b97c1f6f3072460f519b71f89421afc7).

Comment: i did the same but when i am adding XboxLive.signin in scope it is giving error also that same scope is not there in Azure Active Directory so please guide here.

Comment: @Harshilshrivastava You don't need to specify the scope in Azure. You just specify that [when offering the user to sign-in](https://github.com/OpenXbox/xbox-webapi-python/blob/v2.0.11/xbox/webapi/authentication/manager.py#L51).

Comment: Did the same but got seems like a need to configure the Microsoft partner for Xbox

Answer (score 0):

I have Researched A Lot About This And Found That Xbox live scope is a service scope that is already authorized in every client. But service scope doesn't work in `response_type` token. It must be set to `response_type: 'code'`

Comment: You can use the scopes like
`XboxLive.signin` and another optional scope is `XboxLive.offline_access`.

Credit: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63898540/how-to-define-the-scope-for-xbox-while-login-with-xbox-in-laravel)