# How to define the scope for XBOX while login with xbox in laravel

Tags: laravel, microsoft-graph-api, xbox, xbox-live, microsoft-live-connect

Here is the code:

```
"https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=" +
 process.env.MIX_LIVE_CLIENT_ID +
 "&scope=service::user.auth.xboxlive.com::MBI_SSL&response_type=code&redirect_uri=" +
 process.env.MIX_LIVE_REDIRECT_URL +
 "&state=ClientStateGoesHere"
```

This is the scope I have created in the microsoft azure account.

> scope=service::user.auth.xboxlive.com::MBI_SSL

But I am getting below error when open the page for login using xbox.

https://example.com/sign-in?error=invalid_scope&error_description=The%20provided%20value%20for%20the%20input%20parameter%20%27scope%27%20has%20not%20been%20pre-authorized%20for%20this%20client%20application.&state=ClientStateGoesHere

Comment: I've opened a thread on Microsoft's support forum with this same issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/226719/34401-unauthorized34-daemon-app-despite-bearer-tok.html

Answer (score 1):

## Optional Info

I have researched a lot about this and found that Xbox live scope is a service scope that is already authorized in every client. But service scope doesn't work in `response_type` token. It must be set to `response_type: 'code'`

## Your Solution

Change scope to the actual service scope of Azure AD i.e. `XboxLive.signin` and another optional scope is `XboxLive.offline_access` to get refresh token.

By the way, I guess the `service::user.auth.xboxlive.com::MBI_SSL` requires ID@Xbox to use it.

Comment: Its giving me invalid scope on callback url. Any idea? Please help. I want to login with xbox on my website. Can you please give me the directions from where I can find the documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `XboxLive.SignIn` scope, I guess `service::user.auth.xboxlive.com::MBI_SSL` scope requires some of Xbox developer program (like ID@Xbox or Xbox Creators Program)

**What's the difference between these scopes?**

The `service::user.auth.xboxlive.com::MBI_SSL` scope allow you to get authorization from the user and the user doesn't have to authorize your application manually, but it requires some of Xbox partnership program (or something like that).

The `XboxLive.SignIn` scope is available to all users and apps, but it requires manual authorization from user since your app is not considered "trusted" if your app doesn't have any Xbox developer program joined.